# Error when creating new campaign: "Your campaign activity has not been saved"

Tags: campaigncreator

When creating a new campaign using the campaign creator, Sitecore returns an error saying

> Your campaign activity has not been saved.

But when you browse the campaigns using the Marketing Control Panel, the campaign actually has been created.

[image]

[image]

Also after deploying campaigns, it is still not showing in campaign creator. What might be the issue for this?

[image]

This is the error in log file:

```
11324 07:13:19 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP POST
URL https://cas.dgs.com/sitecore/api/ssc/CampaignManagement/Campaign

Exception System.ArgumentException: the definition was not found: {3288EF08-CC53-45E6-9804-29DD1B397695}
Parameter name: definitionId
 at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentCondition(Boolean condition, String argumentName, String message)
 at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<Activate>b__0()
 at Sitecore.Marketing.Core.IgnoreRecursiveCalls.Run(ID id, Action action)
 at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`1.Activate[TRecord](ID definitionId, IDefinitionRepository`1 repository, Func`2 toDefinition)
 at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Campaigns.CampaignDefinitionManager.ActivateAsync(ID definitionId)
 at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`1.Save[TRecord](TDefinition definition, Boolean activate, IDefinitionRepository`1 repository, Action`2 setCustomFields)
 at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Campaigns.CampaignDefinitionManager.SaveAsync(ICampaignActivityDefinition definition, Boolean activate)
 at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`1.Save(TDefinition definition, Boolean activate)
 at Sitecore.Marketing.Campaigns.Services.Data.CampaignRepository.Add(CampaignEntity entity)
 at Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Services.EntityServiceBase`1.CreateEntity(T entity)
 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Did you do Sitecore update on the past? Error sounds like Siteocore update was done, but some steps were missed.

Comment: What I can suggest to try, find item with ID:
{3288EF08-CC53-45E6-9804-29DD1B397695}. Set its workflow to "Workflows/Analytics Workflow" and state to "Draft". Then deploy this item. It will create missed record in Sitecore Analytics DB, if it is reason.